# Problems with Active Directory and WSO2 Identity Server Secondary User Store

Tags: active-directory, wso2

I'm trying to use WSO2 Identity Server with Active Driectory...

Everything seems to be connecting to OK when I go to the `Management Monsole -> Configure -> Users and Roles -> Users`... all the users are listed and I can see the groups with out a problem too. I assigned a group with full permissions on WSO2. That wasn't too hard either.

But when I try to loon with a user in that group I can't... I've tried several permutations of the domain and username.

**username@domain**

> TID: [0] [IS] [2013-10-10 09:22:41,468]  WARN
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.util.AnonymousSessionUtil} -  Failed to retrieve
>   Realm for the Invalid Domain :
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.util.AnonymousSessionUtil} 
>   TID: [0] [IS] [2013-10-10 09:22:41,468]  WARN
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth.BasicAuthenticator}
>   -  Realm creation failed. Tenant may be inactive or invalid. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth.BasicAuthenticator}

**domain\username**

> TID: [0] [IS] [2013-10-10 09:37:43,735] ERROR
>   {org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.codec.LdapMessageGrammar} - 
>   Incorrect DN given : uid=domain\username,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org 
>   unexpected token: b
>   {org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.codec.LdapMessageGrammar} 
>   TID: [0] [IS] [2013-10-10 09:37:43,735] ERROR
>   {org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.codec.LdapMessageGrammar} - 
>   Incorrect DN given : uid=domain\username,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org 
>   unexpected token: b
>   {org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.codec.LdapMessageGrammar}

Nothing seems to work... Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Note that tags stand alone.  Combining `active` and `directory` doesn't mean the same thing as the tag `active-directory`.  You may also review the formatting guide, available by using the large orange question mark in the upper right of the post/edit box.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Identity Server 4.5.0 the latest version. I guess you refer to user store domain of the user here as "username@domain". If so it is not required. No matter what the user store, the user is residing, the user do not have to specify it. This syntax "username@domain" is used in mutitenancy that the user is treated as belonging to the 'domain' tenant.

So please try with just the user name - 'username'. It is obvious for a user to not-know, which user store they are stored at, which is a detail of the system design.

Comment: Thanks for the help...I tried just the username, and I can't log in, but it recording any sort of error in the wso2carbon.log either... Where would I look for problems as they relate to authentication?

Thanks!